# share event specific information in mule 3.3.1

Tags: mule

we have multiple components in a mule3.3.1 flow. 
Once mule receives an event, the first component needs to save the current time in a location specific to that event as it will used by different component at a later stage.

I found out that mule's PropertyScope is not helpful as they are common to all events.
is there a location which is event scope to save values ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you say that PropertyScope is not helpful. Properties are specific to a message which is carried by an event.

If you set a property on an event it will be set only for this event and not for other events.

What have you tried and what haven't worked?

Comment: Thanks @David. I guess , I misunderstood from the mule documentation.